# Source app information in iOS Network Extension App Proxy

Tags: ios, iphone, networkextension

In my current app I've implemented [Packet tunnel provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/packet_tunnel_provider) with local VPN to get traffic going outside the device.

Now my target is to know about the `source application name` through which this network traffic is generated.

For this this I am looking for [App proxy provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/app_proxy_provider) and  I found that [NEFlowMetaData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neflowmetadata#1674644) has the information about the source application. But as per mentioned docs, instance property `sourceAppSigningIdentifier` containing the bundle identifier of the source application.

My question is how to get the application name through bundle identifier. Also, is there any good example available to implement App Proxy along with Packet Tunnel Provider?